# get category image outside of category template in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I get the current category image from outside of the category template (view.phtml)?
for example if I wanted to get it from header.phtml or footer.phtml.

I tried copying the code from view.phtml:

```
<?php
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
$_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
$_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}
?>
```

but i get this error when reloading the page:
     Fatal error:  Call to a member function getImageUrl() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your category with

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($category){

    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Marius,

I tryed this, but when I change the original code for this I get the error `Call to a member function getImageUrl() on a non-object`. I've pasted it in template/catalog/category/view.phtml - What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Check if `Mage::registry('current_category');` returns something .If you are not on the category view page, that should return `null`. The code above only works on the category page, everywhere in the page.

Comment: Hey Marius, I've added the `Mage::registry('current_category');` to the category/view.phtml and it brings back nothing... Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. THanks

Comment: @ArturasStrazdas. What do you mean you added `Mage::registry('current_category');`. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to developing the Magento theme. Maybe I misundertood your comment. You said to check if `Mage::registry('current_category');` returns anything and I added this to the view.phtml to check if it get-s anything and it didn't. Thanks for the help. P.S. I'm developing on RWD Magento 1.9 theme.

Comment: if that returns nothing, it means you don'd have a category instance in your context.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but how should I add a category instance to the context? Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but this is kind of hard to explain. You should get familiarized first with how magento controllers and blocks work and what Mage::register and Mage::registry do. It should be easier then.

Comment: Try either
`var_dump(Mage::registry('current_category'));` or 
`print_r(Mage::registry('current_category'));` and see what Magento returns on the front end.